# $.getJSON not working with simple PHP Script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

The JS doesn't work with the PHP script. I get no response.

Here's the PHP script:

```
<?php

$a = array('data' => 'Hello');
echo json_encode($a);


?>
```

Here is the JQuery Script:

```
function getCityAndState(data, location)
{
    var jsonString = {"zipCode":  data};
    var outR = outputResults    
    alert("JSON String:" + jsonString.zipCode); 
    if (location === "living")
    {   
        $("#livingCityField").val("");
        $("#livingStateField").val("");
        alert("Inside getCityAndState: " + location);
        //$.get("testfile.php", 
        //  {zipCode:  data}, 
        //  outR,
        //  'text'


        //  );

        $.getJSON("testfile.php",function(d) {
                alert("JSON Data: " + d.data);
                });


}
```

What am I doing wrong?

`alert("Inside getCityAndState: " + location);` does execute as expected but otherwise nothing happens. There is no exception thrown, no error message, nothing. It doesn't return any data at all.

I'm using Aptana 2 as an IDE, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: what's the error that your're getting??

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?  If it's 1.5+ you can use `$.getJSON(...).fail()` to let you know if the request is what's failing, which would be my bet.

Comment: What doesn't work, and what does the returned data look like?

Comment: Take a look at your browser's console, are there any errors?

Comment: What is outputResults ? Also looks like you are missing a brace  } to end

Comment: @Pekka on the console there are no errors at all.  It just does nothing.  I'm using JQuery modal windows to get data.  Is that a problem?  But the JQuery itself is triggered by an event handler.

Comment: Is a JSON request ever made? You can see in Firebug's "net" tab for example

Comment: @Pekka.  I'm going to install Firebug right now and see what happens.

Comment: It says the "d" object is undefined.  So the script isn't sending back a JSON object or any object at all it appears.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script is missing the Header, it should be something like:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/json'); //added line
$a = array('data' => 'Hello');
echo json_encode($a);


?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The second parameter of jQuery's `$.getJSON()` function isn't the callback that returns the data, it is supposed to be a map or string containing additional data to be **sent to the server**. The callback function is the third parameter.

I didn't test this, but it should be something along these lines:

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', "", function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    //In here you should have access to the data return by the server thourgh the "data" variable.
});
```

**EDIT:** As very well pointed out by @Rocket and @Tadeck, optional arguments can be omitted and "*rearranged*" since jQuery checks the argument's type. This is the case with the second and third arguments of the `getJSON()` function.
Given that, and although this shouldn't be the source of the problem, it makes sure the function receives all the arguments in the expected order, and it should yield the same result as omitting the second parameter.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: It doesn't matter.  The 2nd parameter (data) can be omitted.  jQuery checks the parameter's type.  The 2st example on the docs page shows this: `$.getJSON("test.js", function(json) {`.

Comment: -1 The second `$.getJSON()`'s attribute is optional! As mentioned exactly within the header of the documentation page you are referring to: `jQuery.getJSON( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] )`.

Comment: Well, The 2nd parameter can be `callback`. I think both supports.

Comment: @Shiplu: In jQuery, optional parameters can be omitted.  It checks the type of the parameters, so you can set the callback to either 2nd or 3rd parameter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I misread the docs. Don't think it hurts to pass the second parameter too, though. It might not solve be problem but at least we're sure the parameters are being passed in the right places and it eliminates a potential source of future problems.

Comment: @Tadeck nice finding. Second parameter would have been required if the syntax was like this `jQuery.getJSON( url [, data [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)]])`

Comment: @Shiplu: Correct. Changing `$.getJSON(url, success)` into `$.getJSON(url, "", success)` has absolutely **no** effect, as the empty string does not even result in "?" being appended to the URL.

Comment: @Pekka on the console there are no errors at all.  It just does nothing.  I'm using JQuery modal windows to get data.  Is that a problem?  But the JQuery itself is triggered by an event handler.